# Data for the number of departing tourists in each country?

Tags: data-request, travel

I'm looking for the number of tourists in each country that go to another country, **not** the number of arriving tourists, which is readily available. Preferably by year.

For example, [here is a ranking of the number of arriving tourists by country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/World_Tourism_rankings#Most_visited_destinations_by_international_tourist_arrivals):

```
Ranking Country Region          Number of arriving tourists
1       France  Europe          84.5 million
2       US      North America   77.5 million    
3       Spain   Europe          68.2 million
4       China   Asia            56.9 million    
5       Italy   Europe          50.7 million
```

But if it is the number of departing tourists, the ranking should be something like this:

1. China
2. US
3. Germany
4. UK
5. France

, with Japan and Russia in a relatively higher rank.

Is there any such data available? (And if at all possible, the data would be better if it is split by region, since the most departing tourists from European countries only travel for another country in Europe).

Any data format (CSV, TSV, XML, JSON, etc...) will do.

Answer (score 3):

I agree it will be hard to find one dataset for all countries. You will have to look for each country individually.

For the Dutch people, here is a CBS report from 2015: [cbs report NL](http://download.cbs.nl/pdf/trendrapport-toerisme-recreatie-en-vrije-tijd-2015.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

I really don't know if there's a way to find this data worldwide, because most countries only track incoming tourists, not where their own people visit (i.e. they track inflow, not outflow).

But if journalist David Yanofksy wins his current FOIA lawsuit, you will be able to get this data for the subset of tourists who arrive in the US, broken down by their country of origin and other statistics:

https://qz.com/685956/im-suing-the-us-government-for-its-data-on-whos-entering-the-country/

Answer (score 2):

Outbound tourism is discussed on page 12 and 13 of the [UNWTO Tourism Highlights, 2016 Edition](http://www.e-unwto.org/doi/book/10.18111/9789284418145).

It is by region instead of country.  On their website, they sell individual country level data, but this is not free unless you are a university academic or conducting bona fide academic research.